# Document.evaluate API behaviour is inconsistent in EDGE browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xpath, microsoft-edge, document.evaluate

*Evaluation of few XPATH expressions results in DOMException (code 12 ---> SYNTAX_ERROR)*

Below are the few XPATH expressions leads to this issue:

1. prefix:_element              (element name starts with _)
2. ancestor::element
3. element[@_attr='value']    (attribute name starts with _)

Will update the few more patterns soon.

```
WARNING## XPATH15001: XPath query "***********" not supported.
```

JS for evaluating the XPATH:

```
 var result = xmlDocument.evaluate(xpathExpression, object,  function(){\\ resolver}, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
```

This issue is only coming in EDGE browser. Can any one please share me the EDGE browser documentation link (like MDN) suggesting what are the APIS supported.

Comment: Well if you get a warning saying "not supported" then it looks like the XPath implementation is not (yet?) ready to work with XML with namespaces. Not much of an XPath implementation then, maybe rather only HPath, i.e. paths on HTML documents.

Comment: A Google search turned up http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/03/19/improving-interoperability-with-dom-l3-xpath/ that suggests that the XPath implementation is based on converting some XPath expressions to equivalent CSS selectors and evaluating others with a Javascript based implementation. Whether that article still holds and explains the problems you see I don't know, maybe you can ask on the blog what they think about the incompatibilities you have encountered.